# Find Places Nearby in Google Maps using Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps

http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/

This Android tutorial is to learn about using Google Places API to find places nearby in Google maps. Ones the app runs then and click the button it wont pass the `googlePlacesJson` values and there by it returns null.

```
12-14 15:06:16.266 6095-6095/com.example.tony_.test_no E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tony_.test_no, PID: 6095
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.tony_.test_no.PlacesDisplayTask.onPostExecute(PlacesDisplayTask.java:42)
    at com.example.tony_.test_no.PlacesDisplayTask.onPostExecute(PlacesDisplayTask.java:18)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 15:06:17.938 6095-6095/com.example.tony_.test_no D/Process: killProcess, pid=6095
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check code below

```
public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
        GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
            Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

            try {
                googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
                googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
                googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return googlePlacesList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            googleMap.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
                String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: here the onPostExecute Null value Please see what can be done

Comment: you got Null, it might you have no internet connection